# jquery combine similar code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many jquery click function, they are very similar, how to combine them for shorter code. (use `regex` or use `array foreach`?)

```
$(".menu").live('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).html();
    $('#menu').html(value);
});

$(".nav").live('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).html();
    $('#nav').html(value);
});

$(".list").live('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).html();
    $('#list').html(value);
});
```

Comment: Question! Are `.menu`, `.nav`, and `.list` all children of some node in your tree besides `document`?

Comment: all in first child nod of `<body>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
var elems = ["menu", "nav", "list"];
$.each(elems, function(i, elem){
    $("."+elem).live('click',function(){
        var value = $(this).html();
        $('#'+elem).html(value);
    });
});
```

1. Create a list of elements.
2. Loop through it using `$.each`
3. The second argument of the function equals the element in the list (`menu`, `nav`, ..)

Comment: Thanks, that is easier than I image.

Answer (score 2):

Rob's answer is definitely vote-up-worthy, but I just wanted to say that sometimes you want to limit the arbitrary connections between two elements.  Why should element X have a class that MUST be the same name as element Y's ID?  It's pretty arbitrary and can be a hassle for people to later figure out.

You can instead approach it like this to make it more robust:

```
<a href="#" class="foo" data-your-data-attr="alice">alice</a>
<a href="#" class="foo" data-your-data-attr="bob">bob</a>
<a href="#" class="foo" data-your-data-attr="sue">sue</a>
```

Now your JS becomes super straight-forward and easy:

```
$(".foo").live('click',function(){
    var value = $(this).html();
    var yourDataAttr= $(this).data('yourDataAttr');
    $('#' + yourDataAttr).html(value);
});
```

Comment: Note that data attributes should be `hyphen-separated`, not `camelCase`. jQuery handles the transition for you - `.data('yourDataAttr')` will refer to `data-your-data-attr`.

Comment: @Eric Most accurate, my mistake on that one.